# For a Poisson Random Variable, is V(cX) = c^2(λ), when c is a constant?

Tags: probability

Example: Y = number of accidents at a particular intersection per month follows a Poisson distribution with a mean of 1.25.

Suppose the cost to the county to respond to and clean up accidents at this intersection each month can be represented by C = 250Y + 85. Calculate the variance of  C.

Can the solution to this be thought of as V(250Y + 85) = 62500(1.25) = 78125? 
Also, how can I conceptualize what the variance in this context is telling me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. In general, if $X$ is some random variable and $c,b$ are real numbers,

$\text{Var}(cX+b)=c^2\text{Var}(X)$.

For large values of $\lambda$, a Poisson($\lambda$)-variable is approximately normal. Then you can think of $\pm 2\text{Var}(C)$ as the interval which $C$ 95 percent of the time will take values in.

*The normal approximation is probably a bit doubtful for $\lambda=1.25$, but the intuition is not!